# How can include the full abstract of a citation in the References section using BibTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I would like to have the abstract (specified in the `.bib` file) for each citation in a paper to appear in the References section.  How can I accomplish this?

The .bib file (generated by Mendeley) has the abstract specified so:

```
@article{RefName,
abstract = {really long abstract},
author = {Author, F M},
journal = {Nano Letters},
keywords = {key,words},
number = {12},
pages = {2728--2735},
title = {{The Title}},
volume = {6},
year = {2006}
}
```

The citation displays fine with

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

but I would just like the full abstract included in the citation, something like

> [1] F M Author. The Title. [*Abstract here, or anywhere*.] *Nano
>   Letters*, 6(12):2728-2735, 2006.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only ready-made bibliography style file I know of that typesets the contents of each entry's `abstract` field in the References (but not as part of a citation call-out) is called [abstract.bst](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/abstract.bst).

As the example below shows, the `abstract` bibliography style isn't programmed to output information (even if present) in the `url` and `doi` fields. If any TeX-special characters (such as `$`, `%`, `#`, and `&`) are present in the `abstract` field, they must be escaped with backslash characters per the usual TeX/LaTeX syntax rules. If the `abstract` field happens to contain any paragraph breaks (as is the case in the example shown below), one must insert suitably-placed `\par` directives if the paragraph breaks are to be preserved.

The `key` field of each entry *is* shown. (In the example below, the `key` field is given by the string `feldstein:2011`.) In fact, the entries are sorted alphabetically on the `key` fields, *not* alphabetically by authors' surnames.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@techreport{feldstein:2011,
   title  = "The {Tax Reform Act} of 1986:  Comment on the 25th Anniversary",
   author = "Martin S. Feldstein",
   institution = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
   type   = "Working Paper",
   series = "Working Paper Series",
   number = "17531",
   year   = "2011",
   month  = "October",
   doi    = "10.3386/w17531", 
   URL    = "http://www.nber.org/papers/w17531",
   abstract = {The Tax Reform Act of 1986 was a powerful pro-growth force 
         for the American economy.  Equally important, as we look back on it 
         after 25 years, we also see that it taught us two important 
         lessons.  First, it showed that politicians with very different 
         political philosophies on the right and on the left could agree on 
         a major program of tax rate reduction and tax reform.  Second, it 
         showed that the amount of taxable income is very sensitive to 
         marginal tax rates. 
         \par
         More specifically, the evidence based on the 1986 tax rate 
         reductions shows that the response of taxpayers to reductions in 
         marginal tax rates offsets a substantial portion of the revenue 
         that would otherwise be lost.  This implies that combining a 
         broadening of the tax base that raises revenue equal to 10 percent 
         of existing personal income tax revenue with a 10 percent across 
         the board cut in all marginal tax rates would raise revenue equal 
         to about four percent of existing tax revenue.  With personal 
         income tax revenue in 2011 of about \$1 trillion, that four percent 
         increase in net revenue would be \$40 billion at the current level 
         of taxable income or more than \$500 billion over the next ten 
         years.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{abstract}
\usepackage{url} % doesn't get used since "abstract" bib style doesn't show contents of 'url' fields
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! That is what I was looking for.