# Have each reference be its own bookmark

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bookmarks

From a Bibtex file I want to create a References section where each reference has its own abstract. For the abstract, I'm using [abstract.bst](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/abstract.bst) mentioned in another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64822/how-can-include-the-full-abstract-of-a-citation-in-the-references-section-using). I am using Lyx. When I generate the bookmarks, it only references the start of the References section. This is no good because I want to able to skim the abstracts and also have the document in a printable/shareable form.

How do I generate the bookmarks with a bibtex file such that it creates a bookmark for each reference? Also, I don't consider this question Lyx-specific.

Comment: I have removed the `bilbatex` tag since in your question you state unambiguously that you use traditional BibTeX. If you care for a `biblatex` solution (which will not be compatible with `abstract.bst` or in fact any `.bst` style) feel free to edit the question to make that clear.